# Want to remove partially matching row in single table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This is the table which consists of the following entries

```
MODEL   VALVE_SIZE  D
PT21-15   2.5      150
PT21-15   2.8      180
PT21-15   3.2      240
PT21-20   2.8      215
PT21-20   3.2      250
```

I want to fetch the rows with value of d is between 150-250 and the model name should not be repeated.
i am using (select model,valve_size from dis where d>=150 and d<250) but i want the output as no row should be repeated with same model name.

Expected Output

```
MODEL   VALVE_SIZE  D
PT21-15   2.5      150
PT21-20   2.8      215
```

Comment: Every model in your sample table is repeated, so wouldn't this mean that you expect an empty result set?

Comment: There are three rows for 'PT21-15' matching the criteria. So which row to show for 'PT21-15'? You haven't specified any rule by which to decide this. What made you decide for PT21-15|2.5|150?

Comment: The rule is to select the first row meeting the condition as PT21-15 meets the condition so need to display it

Comment: There is no first, second, third, ... row in a table. Tables contain an unordered set of rows. So when you say *first*: does this mean *whichever*? You don't care which of the matching rows? We could just as well show PT21-15|2.8|180 instead of PT21-15|2.5|150?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data and output imply that you want a single record for each model having the *smallest* `d` value (or possibly `valve_size` value).  In this case, you can try the following query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT model, valve_size, d,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY model ORDER BY d) rn
    FROM dis
    WHERE d >= 150 AND d < 250
)

SELECT t.model,
       t.valve_size,
       t.d
FROM cte t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: `but i want the output as no row should be repeated with same model name.` ... what does this mean?  You never showed us your expected output.

Comment: this can be achieve using a simple GROUP BY query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script,

```
SELECT  MODEL,
        MIN(VALVE_SIZE) AS VALVE_SIZE,
        MIN(D)          AS  D
FROM    TABLE1
WHERE   D >= 150 AND d < 250
GROUP BY MODEL
```

Comment: This does lead to the output shown, but with different data, you might take the `valve_size` of one record and the `d` from another. I don't think this likely to be what the OP is after.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yes you are rgt, if the OP want the minimum(D) and the corresponding  VALVE_SIZE, then it may not work properly.